# Open source tool to draw GUI mockups

Tags: linux, open-source, gui, drawing, mocks

I want to draw a sketch for a graphical user interface.
Is there a slim open source software for Linux to draw user interfaces?

I used sometimes the combination of [Qt designer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) and Inkscape or Gimp as workaround, but I prefer to have it in one tool and without the need of the very large Qt suite.

- open-source and free of charge
- runs on Linux
- draw GUI items (buttons, windows, textboxes, scrollbars)
- draw annotations (arrows, annotations, freestyle pen)
- objects in saved files should still be editable (no flat screenshot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) can be used both online and offline (you can [download for Linux](https://about.draw.io/integrations/#integrations_offline)), it's [open source](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio), can draw GUI items and annotations, and allows you to save the file locally or on the cloud to edit it later (file is saved in XML format).

Answer (score 4):

[Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/Default.html) is a tool I have used for UI mockups.
And there’s quite a few tutorials for it on YouTube.

Comment: Last contribution to the sourcecode was 2019 https://github.com/evolus/pencil several of the 400 open issues have "does not start" or "crash" in the title.

Comment: https://alternativeto.net/software/pencil-project/ - look here for alternative tools.

Answer (score 0):

I just found [quickmockup](https://jdittrich.github.io/quickMockup/)
[image: A mockup image made with quickmockup]
it seems there was a version bump to 2.x but 2.x has no commits since 2020 and the demo page had less functionalities than the 1.x Demo.